# Failed WATIR installation Server 2003

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir, activesupport

I had to rebuild my box and I currently am unable to install Watir.

> gem install watir
>   ERROR:  Error installing watir:
>           activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7.

Which would be fine if Watir was able to use Ruby 1.8.7 .  I am using

> ruby -v
>   ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [i386-mswin32]
>   gem -v
>   1.3.7

I am not sure when this started to occur, but the documentation on the site is lacking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows XP (Professional, Version 2002, Service Pack 3, fully pathched) I have installed [ruby186-26.exe](http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/29263/ruby186-26.exe) from [RubyForge](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=167), as suggested at [watir.com/installation](http://watir.com/installation/).

```
C:\>ruby -v
ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i386-mswin32]

C:\>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - VERSION: 0.9.4 (0.9.4)
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM PATH:
     - c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org
```

Automatic RubyGems update did not work:

```
C:\>gem update --system
Updating RubyGems...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException)
    HTTP Response 302
```

I have downloaded [rubygems-update-1.3.7.gem](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126) from [RubyForge](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126), copied it to the folder where I have command prompt open (`C:\` in this example) and installed:

```
C:\>gem install rubygems-update-1.3.7.gem
Successfully installed rubygems-update, version 1.3.7
Installing ri documentation for rubygems-update-1.3.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for rubygems-update-1.3.7...
Could not find main page README
Could not find main page README
Could not find main page README
Could not find main page README

C:\>update_rubygems
RubyGems 1.3.7 installed
...
```

To make sure I have the latest RubyGems:

```
C:\>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i386-mswin32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: c:/ruby/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: c:/ruby/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mswin32-60
  - GEM PATHS:
     - c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Now Watir did not want to install:

```
C:\>gem install watir
ERROR:  Error installing watir:
        activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7.
```

I have installed activesupport-2.3.8 as [suggested by Charley Baker](http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/browse_thread/thread/cd2ce989784fa854), and I was able to install Watir:

```
C:\>gem install activesupport --version="2.3.8"
Successfully installed activesupport-2.3.8
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-2.3.8...
Installing RDoc documentation for activesupport-2.3.8...

C:\>gem install watir
Successfully installed firewatir-1.6.5
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.4.3.1-x86-mswin32
Successfully installed watir-1.6.5
3 gems installed
...
```

Comment: Download the Rubygems from the web instead of from the Ruby way.  Also how does this help with watir?

Comment: Sorry, I have saved the answer when in the middle of investigation, I did not want to lose it if my browser crashed (or something). I have updated the answer with the solution.

Comment: all that for the real fix: $ gem install activesupport --version="2.3.8"

Comment: rogerdpack I believe you may be the only person in the whole of I.T. that is complaining about too much detail

Comment: @rogerdpack: well activesupport was not the only problem here, automatic rubygems update did not work too

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue just now and thought I would add a comment to this issue. Our dev vm's are currently running windows 7, therefore I needed to run my command prompt as administrator for the gem installation to work correctly.